# Pipe-ing perf output into a file

Tags: bash, unix, perf

I'm trying to obtain a rough idea of the number of flops a python script is generating. I'm using `perf` as follows:

```
perf stat -a -e fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_single,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_single,fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_double,fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_single,fp_assist.any -B  ./abc
```

Inside my `abc` script I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/usr/anaconda3/bin/python flops.py
```

My question is how do I get the output of the command into a file ? I tried appending to the command above `> output.txt` however it's only the output of the python script that gets inserted into my `output.txt`. I'd like the result of `perf stat ...` to be put into a file.

Comment: Have you tried `>output.txt 2>&1`?

Comment: It works! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: It has been asked before, at least a hundred times. Let me find a duplicate instead